# Is it bad form to turn down a job offer after asking colleagues to give references?

Tags: hiring-process, references

I am happy at my current job, but I am considering moving to a new job (at a more risky startup).  The interviews have all gone well, but I'm not sure about long hours and low pay.  I have, however, asked a bunch of former colleagues to give me a reference, and they have all graciously given me glowing reviews.  Now, I feel conflicted about turning down the job (though I haven't made up my mind either way).

Is it rude to my former colleagues to turn down a job that they tried to help me get?

Of course, I think highly of all of these colleagues (which is why I chose them as references) and I would like to remain on good terms with them, in case I need a reference in the future, or if they need mine, or if we end up working together again down the road.

Comment: No, it's not rude.  Not unless your colleagues were volunteering to work the long hours at low pay for you.  If you're really concerned about it, why not just tell your colleagues that you didn't get an offer?  Or that you got an offer, but couldn't come to an agreement on compensation?

Comment: Nothing wrong with turning down the job, as far as your colleagues are concerned. They shouldn't feel any pressure from you to take the job, if they were in your shoes and you were in theirs. You would be just as gracious in giving out your references, without any specific or general expectation that they will take the job offer. People turn down job offers every day day for myriad reasons. Don't feel that because someone made you a job offer, ergo, you are chained to it.

Comment: Did they "just give a reference" or did they really go out of their way to possibly introduce you to the company and get involved more than normal to help you get the job?

Comment: If it was rude, no-one would ever apply for more than one job at the same time.

Comment: @starplusplus: that's naive, inefficient and most probably ignorant, too. You HAVE to apply to more than one job at the same time because if they screen you out without notifying you, you'll be waiting and waiting for them to answer before you decide that your job app was a dud and file your next job app.

Comment: I've given and recieved lots of references over the last 20 years in the software development business.  

I may mention a specific job I'm looking at, but in general when one provides a reference, that reference is a general one, not specific to one particular position.

If a friend actually gets me in the door for an interview then of course I thank him profusely and let her know how things turned out.

In neither case would any professional expect the referred person to accept a position for which he or she does not feel suited.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan - that's kind of the point. I've often acted as a reference for a former colleague for multiple job applications at the same time. I expect that they will very possibly get multiple offers, and of course if they do, they will turn some of them down. Hence, I would never consider it rude for someone to turn down a job offer that I went referee for.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan - I think that was _exactly_ starplusplus's point.

Comment: @starpluplu: I owe you an apology.

Comment: Not sure if what you suggest is bad form, but I know taking a job simply because of guilt is bad form.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No nothing wrong in that. They referred you but final decision needs to be taken in terms of your gaining as compare to your current company. If you are not satisfied with the offer you will not accept it. It's very practical thing.

There will be many times you pursue job opportunities that look good at first but over time you realize you aren't interested in. This can occur at any point in the process be it the recruiter interview, technical interview, offer, and even after the time of hire. That said sometimes you'll have professional favors such as references involved. It's nothing wrong as long as it's not a chronic problem. I'm a strong believer in one professional favor per person. You only ask and grant a favor professionally once per person. (Just to mutually avoid abusing connections)

Answer (score 13):

> Is it rude to my former colleagues to turn down a job that they tried
>   to help me get?

**No, certainly not.**

This is *your* job, *your* career, *your* life. Just because your friends did you a favor by providing a reference, doesn't mean you are obliged to them such that you should take a job you don't want.

If they are your friends, they may be disappointed, but they will want only what is best for you.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is ok. But in the future you should wait with giving references until you are sure you want the job. Usually for me references have been given after the interviews and before salary discussions.

You must remember to write your references to let them know what you decided and why, and also to thank them for their help. A beer at the local pub is generally the agreed upon price for being a reference :)

Comment: Many times companies will ask for references long before they extend a job offer, in order to make a better hiring decision. As a result, usually you don't know if you'll accept the job by the time you have to provide references.